# AS3: Avoid collision

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a screensaver and within the content it has a lets call it 'main fish' just swimming around. I managed to do that part of coding where the main fish is just swimming. Now I have added smaller fish following the main fish which i was able to do but how can i make the small fish stay behind the main fish, as in not collide with it or the other fishes following the main fish. This is what I have done so far

This is the fish class (the one that is following)

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.Point;

    public class Fish extends MovieClip
    {
        var speed:Number = 3;
        var target:Point;

        public function Fish()
        {
            // constructor code
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        }

        function update(e:Event)
        {
            //Point fish at main fish
            var dx = MovieClip(parent).mainfish01.x - x;
            var dy = MovieClip(parent).mainfish01.y - y;
            var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;
            rotation = angle;

            //Move in the direction the fish is facing
            x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*speed;
            y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*speed;

            //Calculate the distance to target
            var hyp = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a max distance, and then check the distance before updating location

```
    function update(e:Event)
    {
        //Point fish at main fish
        var dx = MovieClip(parent).mainfish01.x - x;
        var dy = MovieClip(parent).mainfish01.y - y;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx) / Math.PI * 180;
        rotation = angle;


        //Calculate the distance to target
        var hyp = Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));

        // calculate based on size
        var minDist = 10;
        if(hyp > minDist){
            //Move in the direction the fish is facing
            x = x+Math.cos(rotation/180*Math.PI)*speed;
            y = y+Math.sin(rotation/180*Math.PI)*speed;
        }
    }
```

Comment: and you shouldn't calculate the true distance, but use the square of distance, because that way you can avoid calculating a square root, which is an expensive function, but on a few fish you wouldn't notice a difference.

Comment: Thanks Daniel that worked like a charm. Just recently I found out about steering behaviors which looks pretty awesome. I just need to sit down and study upon it but thanks for that.